# How to change microprocessor Clock Speed

Tags: cpu, clockspeed

How to change microprocessor Clock Speed for Inter P III and Intel GS810 Motherboard  ?

Comment: Of what hardware? I can vary a little bit (CPU & Motherboard)

Comment: Intel P III and Intel GS810 Motherboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go into your bios. [Here is some steps](http://www.wikihow.com/Overclock-a-PC).

Answer (score 2):

This really depends on the motherboard and the processor. Many MBs have support for underclocking built right into the BIOS configuration settings. Fewer have support for overclocking built in. Most mobile and even some desktop processors support decreasing processor speed based on runtime conditions (PCs idle state, power management settings, running from battery or outlet) this is known as powerstepping.

Older MBs used jumpers to control the clock speed and voltage of the processor. This is where the idea of overclocking really began to take off.

Comment: Before the jumper days, it was based on a single physical clock crystal.  We used to unsolder the original, then solder in varying faster crystals to do our overclocking.  I don't miss those days.  :-)